# Public PHP hosting returns unwanted HTML response

Tags: php, nginx

I have this PHP code and is working perfectly in my local host.

1.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$resultArr = [["id"=> "000000000001", "name"=> "qwer"], ["id"=> "000000000002", "name"=> "aaa"]];

echo json_encode($resultArr);

http_response_code(200);
?>
```

Result:
[image]

but when I upload it to a public hosting it returns unwanted HTML response:
[image]

the weird part is it is working fine in web browser:
[image]

My localhost uses Apache while my public hosting uses Nginx.

Any idea guys?

Comment: Ask your hoster. He may inject that.

Comment: And if he does that, immediately change your hoster ;) 
Years back I had clients who complained about terribly looking images on the pages, which I couldn't reproduce.. Turned out: their hoster reduced the image quality on the fly to save bandwidth.